# What should a community ad for coffee.stackexchange look like?

Tags: discussion

Fully launched StackExchange sites can show community ads for anything their community chooses. There are premade templates for ads for Area51 proposals:

[area51 ad http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/61013.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/61013.png)

but they're perhaps not the best for betas, since they still say "proposal" and are pretty generic. Is the premade one good enough? Or does anyone have something they'd like to offer up as an ad for any sites interested in advertising for coffee?

For example, [text on a simple image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247044/133299) can look good. Here's one from space:

[image: space community ad]

Here are the image requirements:

> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Comment: Are you thinking of posting these anywhere other than Seasoned Advice? (I'm trying to think of other graduated sites that would be interested in hosting these, but coming up rather short.)

Comment: @abbyhairboat I'm personally just asking because of Seasoned Advice, but figured it was at least possible another site might want it.

Comment: I agree with you - great fit for SA and maybe someone else will get interested. (Programmers love coffee...)

Comment: I should say that initially I wasn't too wild about advertising for coffee on cooking because coffee has always been on topic there and the proposal was unlaunched (and the area51 ad got downvoted), but I think now that it's in beta and the ad will be sending people somewhere they can actually ask questions, it's a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 11):

[Yes, this size will work fine](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015), and it'll look nicer on high-dpi screens.

[image]

Comment: Nice work. I like this.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else comes up with anything then post this as a candidate on cooking.

Comment: @Jefromi I was a bit cheeky and already [posted it on programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7177).

Comment: Awesome! Any more ideas?

Comment: @PythonMaster Sites aren't really going to show more than one ad for a given target, so unless fredley comes up with something you like even more than this (and whatever others post), a second ad probably won't get used.

Comment: @fredley The community-driven advertisements/bulletins have to be at least roughly aligned with the topic of the community. This advertisement is not appropriate for Programmers SE.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Fair enough. I thought anything that was of interest to the community was fair game (especially given their logo is a coffee cup!)

Comment: Posted on cooking! http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/2042/1672

Comment: Could you edit this to change "coffee.se" to "coffee se"? Apparently that's the preferred form.

Comment: @Jefromi Is it? Can you point me to a source for that?

Comment: Yeah, so it doesn't look like a Swedish domain name. (Although in this case coffee.se seems to not exist, so maybe it doesn't matter as much?) http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/306/community-promotion-ads/307#comment1913_307

Comment: just saw this. I love it.

Comment: @Jin Cheers! SE should totally get a stencil [made](http://www.stencilwarehouse.com/acatalog/Coffee-and-Cake-Stencils.html) (I'm pretty sure you can do it with lasers), so that this shop can become a reality. Potential future top user swag?

Comment: @fredley that's a great idea!

Comment: Would you be able to update this for the new ad size? (300 x 250 pixels, or 600 x 500 pixels for retina) Cooking would probably take it again: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2152/1672

Comment: @Jefromi Will do, when we get the official post!

Comment: @fredley Not sure if I'm misunderstanding, but that link is the official 2016 community ad post on cooking.

Answer (score 3):

I dabbled some.

[image]

Comment: Pedantic note: the anti-aliasing on the text could be a little sharper. The edges look a bit jagged to me.

Comment: How is your picture so big?! Mine is like 220 by 250. Your is like 1000 by 1000! Same goes to @fredley.

Comment: @PythonMaster Look at what fredley linked to at the top of the answer, or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248622/what-size-should-community-ads-actually-be

Answer (score 0):

How about coffee beans with a magnifying glass? This could connote the metaphor of examining coffee more closely. Here's [an example from Shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-129990014/stock-photo-man-s-hand-keeps-magnifying-glass-over-the-coffee-beans.html) of what I'm talking about, because I'm not much of a photographer.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Image is by some SE Meta user Attribution://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138755/stack-overflow-mug]

Comment: Should support CR, Programmers, StackOverflow. Attribution is there in the alt= text.

Comment: While it is [possible to make the image double resolution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248622/133299), this isn't the right ratio, so I don't think it'll work.

Comment: The requirement is 0.88, my one is close to 1.33. Not even close. xD