# Community ads for Coffee.SE 2016

Tags: discussion

In the vein of [this previous post](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-should-a-community-ad-for-coffee-stackexchange-look-like/), please share any ads *for* Coffee Stack Exchange in the appropriate size!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Coffee Stack Exchange]

Comment: I saw this ad while on Seasoned Advice. Looks great!

Comment: This needs to be posted on the new [cooking meta question](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/community-promotion-ads-2016).

Comment: @Pureferret Done!

Comment: Try to keep an eye on the new 40K filesize restriction, though (or even the old 150K restriction to begin with).

Comment: @ChristianRau I have compressed it somewhat, it's now ~100kb. There's an ongoing request to up the limit back to 150kb, which it was before. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273200/150214

Comment: Any interest in putting that up on this year's ad threads?