# Has Coffee SE tried making some adds to promote the site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have noticed in particular that Coffee SE hasn't been getting much traffic than it should be getting. Has any of the admins of Coffee SE tried looking into making some ads to post on other more established SE sites (Like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/))?

If not, is there any other ways to help improve traffic on this site besides for advertising?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community ads for Coffee.SE 2016](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/community-ads-for-coffee-se-2016)

Comment: It's not now, it's now been 2 years without a new ad